# Is it possible to reuse overloading type with generic in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I understand that the question may not be clear. Please read the following example.

```
type TypeA = {
  foo: string
}

type TypeB = {
  bar: string
}
enum Schemas {
  TypeA = "TypeA",
  TypeB = "TypeB",
}

type Result<T> = {
  error: string,
  value: null
} | {
  error: null,
  value: T
}

function checkType(schema: Schemas.TypeA, value: any): Result<TypeA>
function checkType(schema: Schemas.TypeB, value: any): Result<TypeB>
function checkType(schema: Schemas, value: any): Result<any>  {
  // Some check
}
```

You can the create overloads for function with specific input. However, is it possible to reuse the relation `Schemas.TypeA -> TypeA` and `Schemas.TypeB -> TypeB` in other functions but using generics?

```
function checkType2<T extends Schemas>(schema: T, value: any): Result<any>  {
  // How to write the return type to achieve same result with overloading?
  // With Some kind of keyof from a mapping object?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can define conditional type based on incoming generics

```js
type RetType<T extends Schemas> = T extends Schemas.TypeA ? ResultForA : ResultForB<TypeB>;
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20TypeA%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20foo%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20TypeB%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20bar%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aenum%20Schemas%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20TypeA%20%3D%20%22TypeA%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20TypeB%20%3D%20%22TypeB%22%2C%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ResultForA%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20error%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20value%3A%20null%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ResultForB%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20error%3A%20null%3B%0D%0A%20%20value%3A%20T%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20RetType%3CT%20extends%20Schemas%3E%20%3D%20T%20extends%20Schemas.TypeA%20%3F%20ResultForA%20%3A%20ResultForB%3CTypeB%3E%3B%20%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20function%20checkType%3CT%20extends%20Schemas%3E(schema%3A%20T%2C%20value%3A%20any)%3A%20RetType%3CT%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20a%3A%20ResultForA%20%3D%20checkType(Schemas.TypeB%2C%20%22a%22)%3B)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a conditional type as suggested by another answer. But a simpler approach would be to use an interface to map between strings and types and use a type query

```
type TypeA = {
    foo: string
}

type TypeB = {
    bar: string
}
interface Schemas {
    TypeA: TypeA,
    TypeB: TypeB,
}

type Result<T> = {
    error: string,
    value: null
} | {
    error: null,
    value: T
}


function checkType<K extends keyof Schemas>(schema: K, value: any): Result<Schemas[K]> {
    return null!;

}

checkType("TypeA", null)
```